# Issues with `msdeploy` (An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis, msdeploy

I have tried the following to deploy a .NET Framework 4.5 application to a remote windows server using Jenkins and msdeploy:

```
def deployDev(folder, virtualDirectory)
{
bat "\"C:\\Program Files\\IIS\\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe\" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:package=\"${WORKSPACE}\\DIST\\Package\\${virtualDirectory}.zip\" -dest:auto=\"Default%%20Web%%20Site/${virtualDirectory}\",computerName=\"https://XX-XXX-XX:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default%%20Web%%20Site\" -enablerule:AppOffline -setParam:name=\"IIS Web Application Name\",value=\"Default Web Site\\${virtualDirectory}\" -verbose -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension"
}
```

While deploying I'm getting the following error:

```
14:29:53  Verbose: Source createApp (E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp) does not match destination (Default Web Site\Aso2) differing in attributes (isDest['False','True']). Update pending.
14:29:53  Verbose: Update operation on **createApp** (E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp) skipped because of rule ApplicationExistsRule.
14:29:53  Verbose: Delete operation on filePath (Default Web Site\Aso2\App_Offline.htm) skipped because of rule AppOffline.
14:29:53  Verbose: Source **setAcl** (E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp) does not match destination (Default Web Site\Aso2) differing in attributes (isDest['False','True'],setAclUser,setAclAccess). Update pending.
14:29:53  Info: Adding ACLs for path (Default Web Site\Aso2)
14:29:53  Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to 'iisApp/E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
14:29:53  Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'setAcl/E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
14:29:53  Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'setAcl/E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
14:29:53  Verbose: Parameter entry 'Add write permission to App_Data Folder/1' is applicable to 'setAcl/E:\Jenkins\slaves\AsoModernisation\workspace\ASO2_master\Aso2\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data' because of its scope.
14:29:53  Error: (21/02/2020 14:29:53) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
14:29:53  Error: The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
14:29:53  Error count: 1.
```

I've opened port 8172, checked user permissions, tried reinstalling msdeploy (v3.6), added IIS Manager permissions, created pools and virtual directories under the default website.

Would anybody have a suggestion on what's wrong with this? Anything with createApp or setAcl that would cause the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, make sure you installed the management service on both the machine.

[image]

and it is running and set windows and iis credentials.

[image]

and open the port 8172.

set iis manager user at sit level.

[image]

Configure the web deploy publishing setting.

[image]

Using IIS generated profile and copy the publish profile.

You could use the profile to publish the application.

[image]

run visual studio as administrator.

and use the profile when you publish the site.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that fixed it.

Thanks!